# Are there any English words with several inflectional suffixes?

Tags: suffixes

I'm very curious about if there are any words in English which have two or maybe even three inflectional suffixes. If they are, then could you please name them?

Comment: It depends to some degree what suffixes you classify of "inflectional", but generally, the answer is no, in Modern English. There are examples in Early Modern English, such as "likedst" (past -d plus 2s -st).

Comment: Do you mean multiple inflectional suffixes one on top of the other in one single word, or a word that has multiple synonymous inflected forms?

Comment: Some candidates: "knowingest", "showings", "givens", "dearests"

Answer (score 0):

inflectional suffix ([vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/inflectional%20suffix))

> an inflection that is added at the end of a root word

English as we know it today only adds one inflectional suffix per morphology.

Further, only one suffix is added among the verb and helping verb.

For example:

> He cook***s***.

> He help***ed*** cook.

> He cook***ed***.

> He do***es*** cook.

> He d***id*** cook.

> He is cook***ing***.

We can consider other words, such as **[antidisestablishmentarianism](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/antidisestablishmentarianism)**:

- anti
- dis
- **establish**
- ment
- ary
- an
- ism

But, this does not employ *inflection suffixes*; it uses [morpheme affixes](https://www.turito.com/learn/english/noun-suffixes-grade-8):